# Rename multiple folders containing special characters

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, batch-processing

I'm trying to process a folder of a few hundred folders that all have parenthesis and square brackets in the name, but also have an unwanted space before the square bracket that I would like removed.

example: `c:/Documents/MainFolder/Subfolder1Title (Attribute1) (Attribute2) [UniqueNumber ] - []`
(Where the space after "UniqueNumber is the unwanted space"

I would like to write a script that looks for all folders that have " ] - []" and replace it with "] - []" without changing the rest of the folder name, so that it ends up as: `c:/Documents/MainFolder/Subfolder1Title (Attribute1) (Attribute2) [UniqueNumber] - []`

I've tried several solutions from other questions, but most deal with just files instead of folders, and for some reason there's an issue with the square brackets that just seemingly can't be resolved. ( with use of `` before the [ )

**Example:**

```
$dir = "c:/Documents/MainFolder/"
CD $dir
Get-ChildItem | `
Where-Object {$_.Name -match ' ] - []'} | `
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_fullname -NewName $_.fullname.replace ( " ] - []" , "] - []")
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. I will just answer the first question which is related to your question title.

- The `-match` takes a *regex*, therefore you have to *escape* the `[`.
- `$_fullname` is missing a dot.
- Since you are using [powershell-v2](/questions/tagged/powershell-v2), you probably have to use curly brackets.

This should work:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '\s+]\s+-\s+\[]'} | 
Rename-Item  -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "\s+]\s+-\s+\[]" , "] - []"})
```

---

**Note:** You should *not* change the directory, instead specify the path within the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

Here the script I used that works:

```
$dir = "c:/" # changed this to C:/

# Create a Sample folder
$sampleFolderPath = Join-Path $dir 'Subfolder1Title (Attribute1) (Attribute2) [UniqueNumber ] - []'
New-Item $sampleFolderPath -ItemType Directory -Force

# Now lets rename it
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -match '\s+]\s+-\s+\[]'} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "\s+]\s+-\s+\[]" , "] - []"})
```

Comment: Sorry for the double question, I tried the code and I get the following message in red: Rename-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LiteralPath'.
At line:5 char:25
+ Rename-Item -LiteralPath <<<<  {$_.fullname} -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "\s+]\s+-\s+\[]" , "] - []"
})
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: You need to keep `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ' ] - []'} | `

Comment: I guess the main issue is the fact that even with this script, i'm unable to replace anything, even without the brackets, so for example, ifI try to replace anything that has "USA" to "US", it still throws me the "Rename-Item: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LiteralPath'" error, so I'm not sure if this is an issue that applies only to folders

Comment: When I changed '-LiteralPath' to '-Path' I get an error that states the item can't be renamed because it "doesn't exist" even tho it lists the entire path to the item

Comment: It is working for me. You should reduce your question to a bare minimum to reproduce your problem. Like provide a script that create a folder with a name and how you try to change the name.

Comment: Well say my main folder right now only has two folders in it: "Job1 (New York) (USA) - [1015 ] - []" "Bill (Toronto) (Canada) - [0305 ] - []" I tried using the code above (with your modifications) to remove the space, but it still gives me those parameter errors

Comment: but now, even when I use just `Get-ChildItem |
Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'USA'} |
Rename-Item -LiteralPath {$_.fullname} -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "USA" , "US"})` it still gives the same parameter error

Comment: As I said, this works for me. Change your question to that specific topic, show exactly the script you run.

Comment: Just omit `-LiteralPath {$_.fullname}` since you are piping the result from GCI....

Comment: This is the exact code I'm using right now as of this post `Get-ChildItem |
Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'USA'} |
Rename-Item -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "USA" , "US"})` I still get the "cannot rename because item doesn't exist" error

Comment: It says `Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\MainFolder\Job1 (New York) (USA) [1015 ] - []' does not exist.`

Comment: If I run the code in PowerShell V2 that you provided, with a folder named USA, it gets renamed to US.

Comment: I changed the question, please let me know if I need to edit it further

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm a little confused now about what version of powershell I even have..when I ran the $PSversiontable command I was shown this `Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1`  but my powershell ise version shows as 1.0

Comment: I edited my answer with a script that I was expecting from **YOU** to provide us. Anyhow, I can't reproduce that and im sure that this will work for you too.....

Comment: My apologies, I thought I did provide the script.  I'm a complete novice to powershell, so I'm not even sure what I'm doing honestly.  At best, I toyed with a couple different scripting languages in the past that allowed me to learn by recording macros, and go from there..  All I did was try to research this problem for days now and try the different scripts that I've found in other answers, I was able to find a working one to append some text to the end of a folder, but I messed up by adding the space, and I couldn't undo that

Comment: Everything is fine, just for the next question you should reduce it to a bare minimum so its easier to us to read the question and finally help you.

Comment: This is the error using your exact revised code `Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\MainFolder\TEST\Subfolder1Title (Attribute1) (Attribute2) [UniqueNumber ] - []' does not exist.`

Comment: hmmm. try to replace the last line with `ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path {$_.FullName} -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "\s+]\s+-\s+\[]" , "] - []"})}`

Comment: Maybe this issue is because I'm on Powershell 1.0?  I thought I was on 2.0 since that's what that $PSversiontable led me to believe, I checked my System32 folder and in the powershell folder it just says v1.0, so I guess I'm not on 2.0 like I originally thought

Comment: even making a new folder called "TEST" and trying to rename it ended in this result `Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'TEST'} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "TEST" , "testing"})

Rename-Item : Cannot rename because the target specified represents a path or device name.
At line:10 char:16
+     Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName ({$_.fullname -replace "TEST" , "testing"})
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand`